# Is there any way to share one laptop's monitor with another laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, display

As you may know, It is possible to connect two monitors to a single computer. I want to know if is there any way to use my ASUS laptop's monitor as a supplementary monitor for my VAIO laptop for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Remote Desktop on either of those and then try to connect from one to another. Be sure to put those on the same network. (you can use wireless router, you can use Connectify to make one of those an AP and connect the other one to it, you can even use internet but it is not secure.)
There are nearly lots of tuts out there to how enable it on windows 7, you can find one [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+enable+remote+desktop+windows+7).

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesnt do exactly what you want, you might want to look at [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/).  Synergy lets you use one keyboard and mouse for multiple computers/OSs.  It doesn *not* extend your desktop, but allows you to use a one set of inputs for multiple machines.  It might do what you are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 and above you can accomplish this with the standard RDP (Remote Desktop Client / mstsc.exe). Here's how:

> **/span for multiple monitors**
>
> If you pass /span to mstsc.exe, the target session’s desktop will
> become a huge rectangle that equals to the summary area of your
> physical monitors. This way the remote desktop window will fill all of
> your screens. The downside of this approach is that both screens are
> part of one desktop on the remote machine, so if you maximize a window
> there, it will span all of your monitors. Also, a dialog that is
> centered, will show up right on the border between your monitors.
> There is software on the web to workaround that but I’m fine with
> keeping my windows restored and sizing them myself. Also Tile
> Vertically works just fine in this case.
>
> **Saving the /span option in the .rdp file**
>
> *There is a hidden option that isn’t mentioned in the description of
> the .rdp format:*
>
> `span monitors:i:1`
>
> The screen mode is by default `mode id:i:1`, which is windowed. To make if fullscreen set it to `mode id:i:2`

---

**SOURCE:**

You may want to see [THIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/04/10/remote-desktop-span-across-multiple-monitors.aspx) for further explaination.